# Swift JSON decode & encode with different results

Tags: arrays, json, swift

)

I have a (maybe) simple problem I can't solve by myself.

First I have a simple JSON File:

```
{
"results": [
{
"entryID":10,
"date":"24.12.201", 
"category":"Best",
"title":"Example title",
"textBody":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod.", 
"link":"http://www.example.com" },
{
"entryID":9,
"date":"24.12.201", 
"category":"Best",
"title":"title for ever",
"textBody":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero.", 
"link":"http://www.example.com" }
]
}
```

I use following struct for encoding:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [JSONResult]
}

struct JSONResult: Codable {
    var entryID: Int
    var category: String
    var title: String
    var textBody: String
    var link: String
}
```

Decoding works as expected.

If I want to save the JSON to file with this func:

```
 func convertAndSaveFavoritestoJSON(item: JSONResult) {
        
        guard let url = URL(string: documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Favoriten.json").absoluteString)
                else {
                    print("Invalid URL")
                    return
                }
        
        do {
            let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(favorites)
            let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
            print(jsonString)
            try jsonString.write(to: url,
                                 atomically: true,
                                 encoding: .utf8)
        } catch { print(error) }
      
    }
```

the file on disks looks like following (the results array is missing):

```
[
{
"entryID":10,
"title":"Favorit","textBody":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.",
"category":"Hardware",
"link":"http:\/\/example.com"
}
]
```

What can I do to save my struct in the same array format like my source?

Any hints are welcome :-)

Thank you
Michael

Comment: I forgot these: @Published var favorites = [JSONResult]()

Comment: You are saving `[JSONResult]`, and you want to save a `Response`? So what about `let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Response(results: favorites))`?

Comment: Sure! Thank you. I had accidentally deleted the (Response(results: favorites) and didn't recognized that. I looked to long on the code for today...

Comment: Note that you can remove absoluteString when initializing your URL. `let url = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Favoriten.json")` that's all you need

Comment: Btw no need to convert your data to string and back to data. you can simply write your jsonData to that URL. `try jsonData.write(to: url, atomically: true)`

Comment: @Leo. Yes you are right. I copied this line from another func where I merged a url and a string together... in this func I use explizit file name. Thanks for the hint. After I   building some new features I have to do some house keeping in my code :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to Larme!
This is the right answer:
You are saving `[JSONResult]`, and you want to save a `Response?`. So what about

```
let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(Response(results: favorites))
```